# Генерация псевдослучайного набора символов

Tags: javascript

Привет. Думал, как можно реализовать генерацию случайного набора цифр и букв и в голову пришла идея использовать **unix timestamp**(заодно и время добавления в базу можно узнать). Для пущей реалистичности(чтобы смотрелось круто и было похоже на хэши) решил, что нужно добавить и буквы. В общем, алгоритм должен быть следующий:

Есть UNIX-дата в формате `1500972916`. Длина этой строки - 10. Количество добавленных букв должно быть 10-(3-5)(**то есть от 5 до 7**). Буквы должны случайно генерироваться и вставляться между числами. После каждой цифры случайным образом вставлять одну/две/три буквы или не вставлять ничего. Должна получиться строка вроде этой: `1a50kbf09j729h1g6o`. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Это не будет похоже на хэши, достаточно получить уже пять-десять таких значений, чтобы увидеть, что тут юникс-дата

Comment: зашифруйте дату каким нибудь AES, результат представьте в base64, например

Comment: @andreymal то, что там UNIX-дата - никакой нагрузки не несёт. Это не функционал хэширования и не функционал шифрования, а это будет функционал сокращения параметров URL. Вместо того, чтобы в адресной строке было 5-6 параметров, я значения сохраню в базу данных с ключом `1a50kbf09j729h1g6o` и выведу этот ключ в URL в качестве единственного параметра: `?search=1a50kbf09j729h1g6o`. А потом при запросе страницы по этому же ключу смогу достать его из базы вместе с данными.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin в таком случае просто берите несколько случайных букв и не надо городить таких сложностей

Comment: @andreymal как их тогда вставить между цифрами?

Comment: Не берите никаких цифр, не надо городить ненужных сложностей

Comment: А зачем вам вообще нужны цифры в этом значении, да еще такие угадываемые, как время

Comment: И кстати, хранить в БД такие длинные текстовые ключи не очень хорошо. место занимают и ищутся дольше, чем простой id int. Пусть БД назначает ID записи, как ей удобно, а вы этот ID шифруйте обратимым шифром. Получив ссылку от клиента просто расшифровываете ее и получаете знакомый БД ID

Comment: Переводите юникс дату в hex и выше(32 разрядеую). Оформить ответом смогу минут чз 15

Comment: @Mike вы не совсем верно поняли принцип моей задачи. Пользовать вводит в поиске какое-то значение и выбирает параметры поиска. Когда он переходит на страницу с результатами, то в адресной строке тихий ужас - много параметров. Так вот, когда пользователь переходит на эту страницу, то я буду брать его параметры, вставлять их в базу, а потом без перезагрузки страницы удалять все его параметры и вставлять лишь один - ID поиска. Но идея с `id` записи в БД мне нравится.